# Ggplot minor gridlines not showing when they coincide with (disabled) major gridlines

Tags: r, date, ggplot2, gridlines

I created a graph plotting data by day of the year with an x-axis where the tick marks  indicate the start of each month and the minor grid lines indicate the start of each week.

I intentionally don't show the major grid lines on the x-axis, which would make the graph too busy. However, this has an unexpected effect: the minor grid lines don't show when they coincide with a (disabled) major grid line. (That is, whenever the first day of the month falls on a Monday, here, Jan 1st and Oct 1st 2018.)

Could this be a bug, and is there a way to work around this issue?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

dat = tibble(
  date = as_date(c("2018-01-01", "2019-01-01")),
  proportion = c(.2, .8)
)

dat %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = date, y = proportion)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_date(breaks = "1 month", minor_breaks = "1 week", date_labels = "%b") +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 1)) +
  theme(
    panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank()
  )
```

[image: graph]

Comment: `panel.grid.major.x = element_blank` removes major grid lines along the x-axis, which is something that I want to do in this graph.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, this is ***intended*** behaviour. See discussion under this (really old) [issue](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/275) on GitHub, which resulted in `ggplot2:::guide_grid` (an un-exported function that manipulates the gridlines before a ggplot object is printed) keeping only minor gridlines that don't overlap with major ones:

```
> ggplot2:::guide_grid
function (theme, x.minor, x.major, y.minor, y.major) {
  x.minor <- setdiff(x.minor, x.major)
  y.minor <- setdiff(y.minor, y.major)
  ...
}
```

**Workaround**

One quick & dirty way to get around this is to run `trace(ggplot2:::guide_grid, edit=TRUE)` beforehand, & manually remove the `x.minor <- setdiff(x.minor, x.major)` line from code in the popup window.

Your code should work as expected thereafter:

[image: plot]

(This effect will end when you close your R session, or earlier if you run `untrace(ggplot2:::guide_grid)`).

Comment: Thanks for the workaround! I'm not sure the github discussion is relevant, since it focuses on avoiding drawing minor grid lines underneath major grid lines. In my graph, there are no major grid lines. But the absence of a major grid line should not affect the drawing of a minor grid line at the same location.

Comment: The major gridlines aren't *displayed* due to the theme specification, but they do exist in the plot's layout. Hence when `ggplot2:::guide_grid` decides which gridline positions require grob creation (an earlier step in the plot drawing process, before theme elements are taken into account), it handles the overlap between major vs. minor based on all the gridlines' positions.

Comment: @Z.Lin Thank you for providing this solution! Do you maybe have an idea about what would be a reproducilble way to do this, since the part with manual editing in a separate box doesn't get saved anywhere?